# Background video play on hover

Tags: jquery, video, background, hover

I am wondering if anyone has suggestions on how to achieve a similar effect like they have on this website http://www.lahautesociete.com/

In particular, how the two different background videos begin playing when you hover over the two buttons.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is not the best place for advice like that. Did you viewing the source, and looking at the elements with the developer tools in your browser? At a wild guess I'd suggest HTML5 and some CSS 3, but that's a guess

Comment: maybe it's a bit like [these examples of websites with video background, some of which are pretty impressive](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/video-backgrounds-2131982)